# Which SQL query should I use?

Tags: sql, database

Given a list containing

```
Province, CustomerName, SalesValue
```

sorted by `Province` and `CustomerName`, describe an algorithm you could use that would output each `CustomerName` and `SalesValue` with the total `SalesValue` per `Province`.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a Euler problem. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first  create a temporary table `temp_table` from your table `list` and use than `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT CustomerName, Province, Sum(SalesValue) from list A
  INNER JOIN temp_table B 
  ON A.CustomerValue = B.CustomerValue
  GROUP BY CustomerName, Province
```